# ¿Cómo enlazar a un ancla en la misma página usando un HyperLink de User Control en Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, .net, vb

Estoy tratando de crear links dentro de la misma página con anclas usando una propiedad de WebControls.
He probado con `<asp:HyperLink` y con `<asp:LinkButton`, pero si trato de cambiar el valor de `NavigateUrl="~/mypage.aspx"` a `NavigateUrl="#mysection"`, lo trata como una ruta relativa, añade el resto de la url y evidenemente no encuentra la página.

```
<asp:HyperLink Id="MyLink" Text="My section"
        NavigateUrl="~/mypage.aspx"
        runat="server" />
```

En el archivo de código VB trato de modificar la propiedad de esta forma:

```
MyLink.NavigateUrl = #mysection
```

Pero esto añade la ruta absoluta delante de mi ancla, como si fuera una página. Encontré una solución, modificando la propiedad `href` en vez de `NavigateUrl`

```
MyLink.Attributes.Add("href", "#mysection")
```

Funciona, pero no me convence. ¿Existe algún modo de especificar que `NavigateUrl` es un ancla? o de evitar que añada el resto de la url?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Solo como referencia, chusmeate esos links.. tu pregunta esta muy bien redactada, seguro alguien podra ayudar... lo que si, tu problema es asp.net, no??? las etiquetas que pusiste, no tendrian nada que ver con tu problema, tal vez habria que cambiarlas...

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré como hacerlo... aunque no lo he compartido hasta ahora.
Simplemente reemplacé la propiedad `NavigateUrl` por la de `href` en la propia definición del enlace por lo que al final quedó algo así, todo en el mismo sitio sin necesitar modificar la propiedad desde la parte de código de VB:

```html
<asp:HyperLink Id="MyLink" Text="My section"
        href="#mysection"
        runat="server" />
```